# Dart HttpRequest & "The built-in library 'dart: io' is not available on Dartium"

Tags: dart, httprequest, dart-io

I want to get json data from the server(tomcat server)

I was import `"package:http/http.dart'` as http".

But, Result is "The built-in library 'dart: io' is not available on Dartium" in Datium console.

So "dart build" and run the "Uncaught Unsupported operation: Platform._version" error comes in chrome console.

Also, dart: html and dart: io's "HttpRequest" was using the request fails.

How can I get response data from the server(tomcat or another was)?

Thanks your answer!!!

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import "dart:html";
import "dart:convert";

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


final ButtonElement loginButton = querySelector("#login");


void main() {

  loginButton.onClick.listen((e) {

requestTest2IO();

  });

}

void requestTest2IO(){

  var url = 'server url';

    http.get(url, headers : {'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',

        'User-Agent': 'xxxxxxx',

        'x-app-stat-json': '(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36,appversion=8}'         

        })

      .then((response) {

        List<String> repos = JSON.decode(response.body);

        print(repos);

      }); 
}
```